# How to make Swiper JS display faction pagination and progress bar at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

How to make it so that the progress bar with the progress line and the numeric display of the active slide from the total number of slides are displayed simultaneously?

Since by default the simultaneous operation of the progress bar and pagination with a fraction is impossible, I added "type: 'progressbar'" in the "pagination" properties, and for the numeric display of slides I made an .image-slider__fraction block in which I placed all the elements.
Then I wrote java script code that I found on the Internet, but I get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: myImageSLider is not defined". Why?

Site ilyin1ib.beget.tech

Code https://jsfiddle.net/qav8z7f3/

[image]

```js
let mySliderAllSlides = document.querySelector('.image-slider__total');
    let mySliderCurrentSlide = document.querySelector('.image-slider__current');
 
    mySliderAllSlides.innerHTML = myImageSLider.slides.length;
 
    myImageSLider.on('slideChange',  function() {
        let currentSlide = ++myImageSLider.realIndex;
        mySliderCurrentSlide.innerHTML = currentSlide;
    });
```

```html
<div class="image-slider__fraction">
                        <div class="image-slider__current">1</div>
                        <div class="image-slider__sepparator">/</div>
                        <div class="image-slider__total">1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **slideChange** `event`. The script does not give the actual number of items because you used the loop inside the slider. That's why I found the value of the items before creating the slider script.

```
var totalSlide = $('.image-slider .swiper-slide').length;
const swiper = new Swiper('.image-slider', {
  // Optional parameters
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  loop: true,
  loopedSLides: 3,
  simulateTouch: true,
  grabCursor: true,
  speed: 800,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'progressbar'
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  autoplay: {
    delay: 1000,
  }
});
//var count = $('.image-slider .image-slider__slide').length;


swiper.on('slideChange', function() {
  var fragment = document.querySelector('.image-slider__current');
  var current = swiper.realIndex + 1;
  if (current > totalSlide)
    current = 1;
  var idx = current < 10 ? ("0" + current) : current;
  var tdx = totalSlide < 10 ? ("0" + totalSlide) : totalSlide;
  fragment.innerHTML = (idx + '/' + tdx);
});
```

demo in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcm641gq/)

Comment: For some reason, I have more slides displayed, and there are only 4 of them and should be displayed 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 and 4/4 . I attached a link with a picture that shows it      https://ibb.co/8Y8cJKj

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You must configure the slider correctly.

Comment: What is not clear? When I inserted your code, in my pagination with a fraction, the number of slides is displayed more than it actually is, namely 6/10, etc. About the settings - the Swiper JS is configured correctly

Comment: yes it works, but another problem appeared: when slides were slid in reverse order, for some reason the slide that was the third in pagination with a fraction is displayed as 1 or 2 and the same with other slides. In the picture that I attached, this slide is the first, and when scrolling back, it displays 3. https://ltdfoto.ru/image/EOHVFG

Comment: I modified the code. I used swiper.realIndex It works properly.